# I get "Your PC needs to be repaired" and "Error code: 0xc0000225" in Windows 8: how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, system-recovery

When I boot my Windows 8 laptop (see details below), it displays this message:

> Recovery
>
> Your PC needs to be repaired
>
> A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.
>
> Error code: 0xc0000225
>
> [ A text saying I should use recovery tools on my installation media
>   to fix the issue. ]
>
> Press Enter to try again
>
> Press F8 for Start-up Settings
>
> Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings

If I press Enter or F8, the central part of the message changes to:

> The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a
>   required file is missing or contains errors.
>
> File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
>
> Error code: 0xc0000225

### My specific situation:

I have an ASUS UX32VD (R4002H) bought just days ago with Windows 8 preinstalled. I was going to swap the internal HDD for an SSD and was messing with the partitions to make them fit into the smaller SSD before cloning. I am not sure exactly what operation I did prior to the crash, but I probably tried to move a partition (which probably was unnecessary anyway).

I have not made recovery disks (yeah, I know).

When I started SystemRescueCD on the laptop and ran testdisk (for the first time in my life), the partitions seemed OK (to my eye), except for something called Backup Boot(sector|loader|?) that was marked as Bad on one of the partitions. I fixed that, to no avail.

I have no physical representation of a serial number (is that a thing of the past?) and I don't know anything about it being somewhere on the disk. I have no installation media, I didn't get anything like that with the computer.

I have contacted ASUS support, but the answer wasn't very technical.

### My obvious question:

How can I get out of this mess? I would prefer if I could repair the partition table or whatever is wrong and get back into the installed OS, but if that is not possible, how can I reinstall Windows 8?

If I need to run a system repair distro from a USB stick and run command line programs, that's no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the product key is on your power adapter (at least it is for my UX32VD).

Comment: I can't find it there, and as far as I understand it from forum comments, it's not there anymore for Windows 8. Do you have a product key for Windows 8 on your power adapter?

Comment: You can buy restore media from Acer, if you cry on the phone they might send them for free. ;-) Sorting out this kind of mess is not a good fit for SU.

Comment: Ah, I got mine with Win7, not Win8.

Comment: Here's the ASUS page on using the recovery partition (hoping that that's not one that's corrupted): http://support.asus.com/Troubleshooting/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=UX32VD&s=411&hashedid=Z9zboGSUuWyLgwXV&os=8&no=1775

Comment: @Moab: I see what you mean, but I was thinking (hoping?) that this might be a general problem with a general solution, and tried to write my question that way. I will understand if the question is closed, though.

Comment: The general answer for most modern systems is to use the recovery partition (which you hopefully have not blown away ;)

Comment: @ernie Thanks for the link. I tried F9 during bootup, and I get into almost the same screen (it doesn't change when pressing Enter/F8 which indicates I am on another partition, I guess). If I mount (when running SystemRescueCD) the recovery, the restore or the OS partition, I can list the files on them, and on the OS partition, the winload.efi file is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to [the comment by Alex S](https://superuser.com/questions/497294/i-get-your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired-and-error-code-0xc0000225-in-windows-8/498689?noredirect=1#comment1586163_498689), here is what I wrote on [the Microsoft Answers page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/i-get-your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired-and-error-code/e17ece75-0c69-4551-a3a1-a4e2ae2e8234) (where I cross-posted my question):

> I have resolved this issue. What I did was a combination of the advice
>   on this page:
>
> http://qliktips.blogspot.se/2012/11/fix-windows-8-boot-issue.html
>
> and setting the correct attributes and properties on the various
>   partitions and volumes using FDISK. I had a strange partition that I
>   removed and one or more volumes was of the wrong type (GUID).

Comment: Detailing the steps, sequence and attributes you changed etc will be a complete answer, that may help someone else as well.

Comment: That is very true, but this was almost four years ago. I simply don't remember.

Comment: `BCDBoot c:\Windows` is what fixed it for me.

Comment: The link above will eventually disappear, making this answer next to useless.

Comment: Since seven years have passed, I think we will have to live with that. All I remember about this is what I can read here.

Besides, I don't think I can or want to just copy-paste the text from Qliktips.

Answer (score 2):

Try several tools for repairing your disk, or consider restarting from scratch.

1. [chkdsk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491051.aspx) (Windows 8 DVD)
2. [Disk Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1782) (Mac OS X DVD)
3. [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) (Ubuntu)
4. [ntfsfix](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/) (Ubuntu, as part of the ntfsprogs package)
5. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (Ubuntu)

Comment: @PeterJaric - Thats the wrong way to mark an answer. I can post 10+ more such tools. 
Each of these options are too broad and not a specific course of action. Please post back on what action + tool actually worked.

Comment: @AlexS: See my newly added answer (http://superuser.com/a/1113158/37364)

Answer (score 2):

I followed these instructions after resizing my Windows 8 partition (in preparation for installing Linux, resizing ntfs, then deleting and adding a new smaller partition entry) which resulted in the exact same error you got.

http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/

Afterwards I received a different error indicating my system needed to be repaired (this seemed marginally better), and I needed to run the "Auto-repair" option from my recovery partition.  After that it booted into Windows fine.

I'm not sure *what* the problem was, as I mounted the resized partition and could confirm that `winload.efi` was indeed there.  One suspicion I have is that deleting and recreating the partition entry confused the UEFI so that it had some dangling reference that didn't resolve to the new partition (and therefore could not find the `winload.efi`).